# Dependencia Circular com ProvidedIn

Tags: angular

Estou estudando os **Services** do Angular e me deparei com **dois modos** de se fazer a **Injeção de Dependência**, os quais são:

**1)** Utilizar o `providers` do module

**2)** Utilizar o `providedIn` das novas atualizações do **Angular 8x**.

E por questão de aprendizagem eu utilizei o primeiro e depois apaguei, e agora estou utilizando o segundo, porém a partir do segundo estou recebendo os seguintes `erros` e `warnings`:

**ERROR:**

```
componente2.component.ts:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Module1Module' before initialization
    at Module.Module1Module (componente2.component.ts:10)
    at Module../src/app/module1/service1.service.ts (service1.service.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/module1/componente1/componente1.component.ts (main.js:542)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/module1/module1.module.ts (componente2.component.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:16)
```

**WARNING 1:**

```
 Circular dependency detected:
src\app\module1\componente1\componente1.component.ts -> src\app\module1\service1.service.ts -> src\app\module1\module1.module.ts -> src\app\module1\componente1\componente1.component.ts
```

**WARNING 2:**

```
Circular dependency detected:
src\app\module1\componente2\componente2.component.ts -> src\app\module1\service1.service.ts -> src\app\module1\module1.module.ts -> src\app\module1\componente2\componente2.component.ts
```

**WARNING 3:**

```
Circular dependency detected:
src\app\module1\module1.module.ts -> src\app\module1\componente1\componente1.component.ts -> src\app\module1\service1.service.ts -> src\app\module1\module1.module.ts
```

**WARNING 4:**

```
Circular dependency detected:
src\app\module1\service1.service.ts -> src\app\module1\module1.module.ts -> src\app\module1\componente1\componente1.component.ts -> src\app\module1\service1.service.ts
```

A mensagem de `warning` me diz como se eu estivesse reutilizando a mesma coisa em outro arquivo e assim continua o ciclo, porém achei bastante estranho, pois apenas removi os `providers` dos modules e inseri dentro dos services os devidos `providedIn`.

**MODULE 1:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { Componente1Component } from "./componente1/componente1.component";
import { Componente2Component } from "./componente2/componente2.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Componente1Component, Componente2Component],
  exports: [Componente1Component, Componente2Component],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class Module1Module {}
```

**MODULE 2:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { Componente3Component } from "./componente3/componente3.component";
import { Componente4Component } from "./componente4/componente4.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Componente3Component, Componente4Component],
  exports: [Componente3Component, Componente4Component],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class Module2Module {}
```

**SERVICE 1:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Module1Module } from './module1.module';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: Module1Module
})
export class Service1 {
  public num: number;

  constructor() {
    this.num = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    console.log("Service1 constructor()");
  }
}
```

**SERVICE 2:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class Service2Service {
  text = "Service 2";

  constructor() {
    console.log("Service2 constructor()");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sempre de provide no root dos serviços

Comment: @EduardoVargas mas porque? Isto é o que eu quero entender.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
```

Com algumas raras exceções se deve sempre usar o provideIn: Root, isso se da porque serviço são singletons e quando se adiciona no root ele fica como um singleton pra toda a aplicação então quando vc injeta a o seu serviço como só tem um ele sabe exatamente qual injetar. O problema acontece quando vc injeta no modulo e ele é lazy loaded, podendo ser carregado varias vezes e consequetemente o serviço é gerado varias vezes assim quando ele é injetado não se tem controle de qual instancia foi injetada assim gerando vários bugs e comportamentos indesejados.

Comment: Então se eu inserir a propriedade ```providedIn: "root"``` ele vai estar dizendo que este determinado serviço será utilizado somente uma instancia dele para todos os componentes o qual ele for utilizado, e não inserir no módulo e sim injetar diretamente no TS do componente por conta do lazy loaded do módulo, é isto?

Comment: então é como se ele tivesse uma pool de serviços ou injetables. Ai quando vc da o provide in root vc garante que so vai ter uma instancia nesse pool global. Ai vc pode ter um pool so do seu modulo mas como cada modulo tera o seu pode se ter varias instancias do mesmo serviço.